# How to find the index of the not-null item which not in a list?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My system is python3.6, with numpy 1.16.2,scipy 1.2.1,matplotlib 3.0.3

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','b','c'],'col2':['d',numpy.NaN,'c'],'col3':['c','b','b']})
df = df.astype({"col2": 'category'})
print(df)
```

output  of above script is:

```
  col1 col2 col3
0    a    d    c
1    b  NaN    b
2    c    c    b
```

I want to find index of the not-null item in series `col2` whose category is not in `['a','b','c']`

In this case, `d` is not `null` and is not in `['a','b','c']`,then the expect result should be the index of `d`,which is `0`

My solution as blow:

```
getindex=numpy.where(~df['col2'].isin(['a','b','c']) & df['col2'].notna())
#if getindex is not empty, print it
if not all(getindex):
    print(getindex)
```

The output of my solution script is:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
getindex=df.index[(~df['col2'].isin(['a','b','c']) & df['col2'].notna())]
print (getindex)
Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
```

If want select first value with no error if value not exist:

```
print (next(iter(getindex), 'no match'))
0
```

If want `if empty` statement use [`Index.empty`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.empty.html) for testing:

```
if not getindex.empty:
    print (getindex)
```

Your solution should working if add `[0]` for select first array from list:

```
getindex=np.where(~df['col2'].isin(['a','b','c']) & df['col2'].notna())[0]
print (getindex)
[0]
```

Comment: result of `getindex=df.index[(~df['col2'].isin(['a','b','c']) & df['col2'].notna())]
print (getindex)` is `Int64Index([], dtype='int64')` even has no match.How to use `if` to print only when something match?

Comment: @kittygirl - So need `print (next(iter(getindex), 'no match'))` ?

Answer (score 1):

Do modify in you if condition

```
getindex=np.where(~df['col2'].isin(['a','b','c']) & df['col2'].notna())
if any(~df['col2'].isin(['a','b','c']) & df['col2'].notna()): # change here to any 
    print(getindex)

(array([0], dtype=int64),)
```

---

Also base on your word `#if getindex is not empty, print it`

```
if len(getindex)!=0:
    print(getindex)

(array([0], dtype=int64),)
```

Comment: @jezrael I am fixing the issue ValueError, since the all will accept the bool, if not all I think she / he want the result getindex output